# If ψ(ϕ)=ln(secϕ+tanϕ), how do you find an expression for ϕ?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

It should be $2\tan ^{-1}\left( e^{\psi }\right) -\dfrac{\pi }{2}$
but i'm not sure whether that is correct or if the $\dfrac{\pi }{2}$ should be in brackets. It would be helpful if you also found an expression for $\phi$ in terms of hyperbolic trig functions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\psi=\ln(\sec\phi+\tan\phi)\rightarrow e^\psi=\sec\phi+\tan\phi$$
Now, using $\tan^2\psi+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}$ and working in $[0,\pi/2]$
$$e^\psi=\frac{1}{\cos\phi}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}-1}=\frac{1}{\cos\phi}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\cos^2\phi}\right)=\frac{1}{\cos\phi}\left(1+\sin\phi\right)$$
$$e^\psi\cos\phi-1=\sin\phi$$
$$e^{2\psi}\cos^2\phi+1-2e^\psi\cos\phi=\sin^2\phi=1-\cos^2\phi$$
$$(e^{2\psi}+1)\cos^2\phi-2e^\psi\cos\phi=0$$
$$\cos\phi((e^{2\psi}+1)\cos\phi-2e^\psi)=0$$
So $$\cos\phi=0 $$ that is excluded by the existence condition or $$\cos\phi=\frac{2e^\psi}{1+e^{2\psi}}$$
$$\psi=\cos^{-1}\frac{2e^\psi}{1+e^{2\psi}}=\cos^{-1}\frac{2}{e^{-\psi}+e^{\psi}}=\cos^{-1}\left({\frac{1}{\cosh{\psi}}}\right)$$